# Turning Milliseconds in Hours without DATETIME

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am running into trouble with SQL code for SQLite. It is a small homework problem I have gotten mostly figured out, but can't find the correct answer for converting an INT to something I can use ROUND with.

```
{sql connection=dbcon}
SELECT 
    genres.Name, 
    ROUND(SUM(CAST(Milliseconds AS DECIMAL(5, 2))) / 3600000, 2) AS 'Hours' 
FROM 
    genres
LEFT JOIN 
    tracks ON genres.GenreId = tracks.GenreId
GROUP BY 
    genres.GenreId
```

This code returns the answer of genres and their total summed track time. But it is required to get the time in hours rounded to 2 decimal points. My use of CAST is not flagged but ignored. Any help in understanding why would be appreciated. Thank you!

Edit: here are the query results

[image: query results]

Comment: Add only the tad for RDBMS you are using.  SQL Server xor SQLITE.

Comment: Alright, thank you, will fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `CAST(Milliseconds AS DECIMAL(5, 2))` does not cast `Milliseconds` to a floating point number (there is no `DECIMAL` data type in SQLite), so the result is an integer and the division performed afterwards will be an integer division which will truncate the result to an integer and `ROUND()` will do nothing.
Instead you should cast to `REAL`.
You can see this behavior [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=a243d5aa676c2e1c4d5f0cd2bba09378).

So, change to this:

```
ROUND(SUM(CAST(Milliseconds AS REAL)) / 3600000, 2) AS Hours
```

or:

```
ROUND(CAST(SUM(Milliseconds) AS REAL) / 3600000, 2) AS Hours
```

or, with an implicit conversion:

```
ROUND(SUM(Milliseconds) / 3600000.0, 2) AS Hours
```

Comment: the implicit conversion worked best. One of my classmates helped explain that I could simply turn the 3600000 into a decimal. Something I now know